# Material UI -Data Grid Custom Pagination

Tags: reactjs, datagrid, material-ui

I am trying to use the custom pagination from here
https://material-ui.com/components/data-grid/style/#custom-theme

however the pagination seems broken itself? Can anyone guide why the pagination is not working and what needs to be done, so that i can implement it?

When I click on page 2, and the click on Page 1, its not working.

Answer (score 4):

I had to update the pagination to

```
    <Pagination
      color="primary"
      showFirstButton
      showLastButton
      page={state.pagination.page + 1}
      count={state.pagination.pageCount}
      // @ts-expect-error
      renderItem={props2 => <PaginationItem {...props2} disableRipple />}
      onChange={(event, value) => apiRef.current.setPage(value-1)}
    />
  )
```

Comment: Hi, I have been searching for this for so long. Thanks for coming back and answering your own question. This helped me a lot. Any Idea why this is happening? I mean setting the page value to current state's value + 1 after setting the current state to value - 1 is just setting the value itself.. So why the -1 then +1?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
function CustomPagination() {
  const apiRef = useGridApiContext();
  const page = useGridSelector(apiRef, gridPageSelector);
  const pageCount = useGridSelector(apiRef, gridPageCountSelector);

  return (
    <Pagination
      color="primary"
      count={pageCount}
      page={page + 1}
      sx={{ color: "#ffffff" }}
      onChange={(event, value) => apiRef.current.setPage(value - 1)}
    />
  );
}
```